# Error in inserting record due to 787 SQLite exception

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I've been for some days now having this error of trying to insert an object, check that it has actually been inserted, then retrieve that object id to create the record in the many-to-many table, but for some reason, I always get the 787 error saying that I'm basically creating this record without existing in the parent table in the first place, which is impossible since, well, I check it just as I create it, and it is there. How can I fix this?

This is the activity where I insert both records (bottom part):

```
package com.gmproxy.pastilarma;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.gmproxy.DAO.AlarmRepository;
import com.gmproxy.DAO.AlarmUserRepository;
import com.gmproxy.Entities.Alarm;
import com.gmproxy.Entities.Medicine;
import com.gmproxy.Entities.User;
import com.gmproxy.Alarm.UtilAlarma;
import com.gmproxy.ViewModels.AlarmViewModel;
import com.gmproxy.ViewModels.MedicineViewModel;
import com.gmproxy.ViewModels.UserViewModel;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class UserAlarmScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView usernameAlarm,numHabText,medicineText,notificationsTime;
    EditText medicineQuantityText;
    Button gotoBackBtn,gotoMedicinesBtn,confirmAlarmBtn;

    int alarmID = 1;
    int idM,idU;

    SharedPreferences settings;
    User user;
    Medicine medicine;
    Alarm alarm;

    AlarmUserRepository alUsRe;
    AlarmRepository alRe;
    AlarmViewModel alarmViewModel;
    UserViewModel userViewModel;
    MedicineViewModel medicineViewModel;

    String medicineQuantity;
    int med_record;

    Calendar today;
    String message;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_alarm_screen);
        context = this.getApplicationContext();

        idU = getIntent().getIntExtra("id_userA",0);
        Log.println(Log.INFO,"id",String.valueOf(idU));
        idM = getIntent().getIntExtra("med",0);
        Log.println(Log.INFO,"Id medicina",String.valueOf(idM));
        med_record = getIntent().getIntExtra("med-record",0);

        /*
        If we come back from medicine search, we actually reload everything that was writter before, so that the user doesn't have to rewrite it
         */
        if (med_record == 1){
            loadPreferences();
        }

        userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(UserViewModel.class);
        alarmViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(AlarmViewModel.class);
        medicineViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(MedicineViewModel.class);
        alUsRe = new AlarmUserRepository(this.getApplication());
        alRe = new AlarmRepository(this.getApplication());


        user = userViewModel.getObjectById(idU);
        medicine = medicineViewModel.getMedicineById(idM);

        usernameAlarm = findViewById(R.id.UsernameAlarm);
        usernameAlarm.setText(user.getUser_name() + " " + user.getUser_surname());
        numHabText = findViewById(R.id.NumHabText);
        numHabText.setText(String.valueOf(user.getRoom_number()));
        medicineText = findViewById(R.id.MedicineText);
        if (idM > 0){
            medicineText.setText(medicine.getMedicineName());
        }
        medicineQuantityText = findViewById(R.id.MedicineQuantity);
        medicineQuantity = medicineQuantityText.getText().toString();
        gotoBackBtn = findViewById(R.id.gotoBack);
        notificationsTime = findViewById(R.id.HoraInput);
        gotoMedicinesBtn = findViewById(R.id.gotoMedicines);
        confirmAlarmBtn = findViewById(R.id.ConfirmAlarm);

        /*
        Now this is pod racing. From here on out until the create method ends, we'll be creating the actual alarm+notification!
        Isn't it exciting!?
        No it's not, please do keep reading.
         */
        settings = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String hour, minute;

        hour = settings.getString("hour","");
        minute = settings.getString("minute","");



        if(hour.length() > 0)
        {
            notificationsTime.setText(hour + ":" + minute);
        }

        /*
         This displays the TimePicker and automatically writes it down for the notification to be created
         */
        findViewById(R.id.CambiarNotificacion).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(UserAlarmScreen.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        String finalHour, finalMinute;

                        finalHour = "" + selectedHour;
                        finalMinute = "" + selectedMinute;
                        if (selectedHour < 10) finalHour = "0" + selectedHour;
                        if (selectedMinute < 10) finalMinute = "0" + selectedMinute;
                        notificationsTime.setText(finalHour + ":" + finalMinute);

                        today = Calendar.getInstance();

                        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
                        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();
                        edit.putString("hour", finalHour);
                        edit.putString("minute", finalMinute);

                        //SAVE ALARM TIME TO USE IT IN CASE OF REBOOT
                        edit.putInt("alarmID", alarmID);
                        edit.putLong("alarmTime", today.getTimeInMillis());

                        edit.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(UserAlarmScreen.this, "Alarma puesta a las " + finalHour + ":" + finalMinute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Escoge una hora");
                mTimePicker.show();

            }
        });
    }


    private void loadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("dataA",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        idU = preferences.getInt("idU",0);
    }

    private void savePreferences(){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("dataA",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editer = preferences.edit();

        editer.putInt("idU",idU);
        editer.commit();
    }



    public void gotoBack(View view){
            Intent mainAct = new Intent(UserAlarmScreen.this, UserInfoScreen.class);
            mainAct.putExtra("id_user",idU);
            startActivity(mainAct);
    }

    public void gotoMedicines(View view){
        Intent mainAct = new Intent(UserAlarmScreen.this, PillsSearchScreen.class);
        mainAct.putExtra("id_userB",idU);
        savePreferences();
        startActivity(mainAct);
    }

    /**
     * Pretty much self explanatory, confirms the alarm and adds it to the database, both to the alarm table and
     * the alarm-user table in order to be shown in the recycler view back at user-info-screen.
     * @param view
     */
    public void confirmAlarm(View view) throws InterruptedException {


        alRe.insertAlarm(medicine.getId_medicine(),
                notificationsTime.getText().toString());


        Log.println(Log.INFO,"Med check null",String.valueOf(medicine.getId_medicine()));
        Log.println(Log.INFO,"Hour check null",notificationsTime.getText().toString());
        int idAl = alarmViewModel.getAlarmbyTimeAndMedId(notificationsTime.getText().toString(),medicine.getId_medicine());
        Log.println(Log.INFO,"Alarm Id Res check null",String.valueOf(alRe.getAlarmbyTimeAndMedId(notificationsTime.getText().toString(),medicine.getId_medicine())));
        Log.println(Log.INFO,"Alarm Id check null",String.valueOf(idAl));
        alUsRe.insertObjectById(idAl,idU);

        message = "El paciente " + user.getUser_name() + " " + user.getUser_surname()
                + " tiene apuntada la medicación " + medicine.getMedicineName() + " a las " + notificationsTime.getText().toString() + " horas.";
        UtilAlarma.setAlarm(idAl, today.getTimeInMillis(), UserAlarmScreen.this, message);
        Intent mainAct = new Intent(UserAlarmScreen.this, UserInfoScreen.class);
        int id = 1;
        mainAct.putExtra("alar-record",id);
        startActivity(mainAct);
    }


}
```

And this is the stack trace:

```
I/Med check null: 12684
I/Hour check null: 01:28
I/Alarm Id Res check null: 26
I/Alarm Id check null: 0
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-2
    Process: com.gmproxy.pastilarma, PID: 6015
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:938)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
        at com.gmproxy.DAO.AlarmUserDAO_Impl.insertIntoAlarmUser(AlarmUserDAO_Impl.java:150)
        at com.gmproxy.DAO.AlarmUserRepository.lambda$insertObjectById$1$AlarmUserRepository(AlarmUserRepository.java:41)
        at com.gmproxy.DAO.-$$Lambda$AlarmUserRepository$2T5LlZH-RbFoUm3l2obKvPWaNZU.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" means that you're trying to insert a record where the column(s) involved in a foreign key constraint do not exist in the target table of that constraint.

Comment: Yeah but they do exist https://gyazo.com/630bb063d4df74be6ffe67eca8077efd . This table follows the same architecture in another many-to-many table I have, and in that one I can insert the records no problem. In this case, both user and alarm exist, for I check them before creating, and so do their IDs

Comment: Do you sure that you already added the dependent data to other tables : usuarius and horario_alarma and try insert data by call to i AlarmUserRepository .nsertObjectById() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it all went down to making sure that the object in java was first created, then inserted. I was getting that error becuase it was being inserted wrongly with id=0, therefore returning error 787.